# Creating a simulation on matlab

Tags: matlab, poisson

[image]

I would like to write a matlab code by using this definition of poisson process

here, I want to simulate a poisson process, where n is chosen randomly between 1 and 10, lambda = 9 for 200 variates.

The codes that I wrote are totally wrong, so I cant post them, please give me a way or hint to do that. Thanks a lot.

My code is as follows:

```
n = randi ([1,10], 200);
lambda = 9;
t=1;
if P == (lambda * t)^n/factorial(n) * e(-lambda * t)
N = n
```

and

```
N_sum = cumsum(N);
disp(N_sum)
```

Comment: `The codes that I wrote are totally wrong, so I cant post them` Then how will we know what you did wrong? Everyone who posts a question on this website either has incorrect code or looking for ways to optimize their code. I don't think you need to be ashamed of your code.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I immediately added my code, can you please help me to show a way dear @KingDuken

Comment: If you look at that definition, a Poisson random variable defines the probability of getting a value of `n` for a given interval `t` and rate `lambda`.  You've specified `lambda = 9`, but haven't specified how long you want your simulation to run.  Also note that a rate is an expected count *per time unit*, and the time unit in that definition isn't necessarily the same amount of time you want to simulate.  For instance, you might have a rate of 9 customers per hour, but want to simulate how many customers you actually see in an 8 hour work day (which may or may not be 72).

Comment: Also note that if you want to stick with `t == 1`, the possible outcomes are not bounded between 1 and 10, you could get 11, or 12, or...

Comment: sorry, I did typo in copy-paste, I corrected, you explained very nice, In fact I 'm statistician, not programmer, and this is not assignment for programming (already classes are close down), I just need to have this code so that I check my statistics question solution which is done by hand. Please can you write this code more clearly. What I did by myself is very limited. @pjs

Comment: many many thanks dear @pjs

Comment: So what specific question are you trying to check?  P{N(t) == 9}?  P{N(t) <= 9}? P{N(t) > 9}?  Saying you want to simulate a Poisson random variable is pretty darn vague, and I can't infer your intent from what you're written.

Comment: in fact, I want to simulate a poisson process with n is randomly chosen between 1 and 10, lambda = 9 and for 200 variates. (This definition is only what I read) you don't have to  depend on this definition. I just want to simulate a poisson process. dear @pjs

Comment: Your coding attempt doesn't make any sense to me.  Where does `P` come from?  Why do you expect to get Poisson outcomes with a mean of 9 when you are uniformly sampling integers between 1 and 10?  A Poisson distribution and a uniform distribution are entirely different.  As I pointed out earlier, and you should know as a statistician, Poisson outcomes are not bounded, and for lambda*t == 9 they can certainly exceed 10.

Comment: I know, I need to simulate poisson **process**. Please don't look at my code, I just posted it because someone ask for why you don't show your attempt. My code is too bad because I know matlab at elementary level. I just need to  simulate a poisson process with n is randomly chosen between 1 and 10, lambda = 9 and for 200 variates. Can you please help me to do this dear @pjs

Comment: You stated you want to check your "statistics question solution which is done by hand."  Stating what that question is would help me and others grasp what your program should be attempting to do.  I'm also a statistician, and right now I have no clue what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just need to simulate poisson process with given information. Just this dear @pjs And I know poisson process and distribution are totally different. I don't mention about poisson distribution. I would like to simulate poisson process.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=80&v=dGsXWwGS7Go&feature=emb_logo

Comment: thank you for that video, but how can I translate this video explanation to matlab code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simulate the Poisson process, you can try the code below

```
t = 0;
T = 100;
lambda = 9;
arrTime = [];
while true 
  t = t - log(rand)/lambda;
  if t <= T
    arrTime(end+1) = t; 
  else
    break
  end
end
```

You will find the reference from https://transp-or.epfl.ch/courses/OptSim2012/slides/05b-poisson.pdf regarding how to simulate it.

Comment: well, wow thank you very much :)) the value n is randomly chosen between 1 and 10. What is that means? dear Thomas

Comment: @B11b `n` is ***NOT*** randomly chosen between 1 and 10.  `n` is the outcome of the Poisson process, and can technically be any non-negative integer, i.e., it can include 0.

Comment: I understand right now. The question that I have states like this way for n. Therefore, I asked it dear @pjs I really confused why the question mentions the n. Thank you again:)

Comment: @B11b `N(t)` is the number of events during `[0, t]`, which is a random variable, `n` can be any non-negative integer to represent the number of events within.

Comment: Rather than write out the inversion for an exponential, why not just use Matlab's [`exprnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html) builtin for clarity?  `mu = 1/lambda` before the loop, and then `t = t + exprnd(mu)`.

Comment: @pjs Good point! Actually I just followed the generator from the reference. Of course `exprnd` would simplify the procedure

Comment: I must admit, until your answer got accepted I still wasn't sure whether OP was asking for the Poisson count or the set of event times for the Poisson process.